# Here maps offset center on JS api

Tags: here-api

I need to offset the center of my here maps. I am using the Javascript api. I found a solution on the ios api with transformCenter property. Is there any similar function on the JS api ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options to offset map's center:

**1. add padding property when initializing the map:**

```js
// assuming defaultLayers is defined
map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
  center: {lat: 50, lng: 20},
  zoom: 15,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
  padding: {top: 0, right: 200, bottom: 0, left: 0}
}),
```

**2. set padding on map's ViewPort object on the fly:**

```js
map.getViewPort().setPadding(0, 200, 0, 0);
```

Here is a simple jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/vq5yazjL/

For more details see documentation for [H.Map#Options](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.Map.html#.Options) and [H.map.ViewPort#setPadding](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.map.ViewPort.html#setPadding)